# How to get the same search results from SDK as in mobile application?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I'm using Google Assistant SDK and I run this [sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/blob/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/textinput.py). I'm able to interact with the Assistant and I get responses. For a query `Play me hip hop on Spotify` as a result I get a response with HTML with a link to a Hip Hop Hits playlist from Spotify. However, the result is completely different from what I get in the Google Assistant on the mobile application.

I would like to get the same playlist from SDK as I get on the mobile application.

In the documentation I found that exist [DeviceLocation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/rpc/google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2#devicelocation) parameters. I tried to set coordinates for Warsaw, London, and LA as in the following code. This didn't affect the result and I always get the same playlist.

```
device_location=embedded_assistant_pb2.DeviceLocation(
        coordinates=latlng_pb2.LatLng(
            #latitude=52.196217,#Warsaw
            #longitude=21.178225,#Warsaw
            #latitude=51.509865,#London
            #longitude=-0.118092,#London
            latitude=34.052235,#LA
            longitude=-118.243683,#LA
        ),
    ),
```

How can I get the same result from SDK as I get in the mobile application for query `Play me hip hop on Spotify`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to just use the SDK to get capabilities like Spotify to play directly on the device. You would need to handle that in a custom way on your device using Spotify's service or some other music provider.

Comment: I know that SDK doesn't get capabilities like Spotify to play directly on the device but Google Assistant returns result for a query with URL to playlist from Spotify. The problem is that Google Assistant for a query `Play me hip hop on Spotify` returns a result with a URL for a playlist on Spotify and this URL is different from the SDK and the mobile application. I would like to get the same playlist.

Comment: On a mobile device, Spotify will be called directly. It seems like through the SDK you'll get Google's search results and nothing more.